# how do I flip (horizontal) the entire virtual camera?

Tags: obs

Certain video conferencing apps mirror the input so it needs to be flipped when coming out of OBS or it will show backwards.

So far I have been achieving this by flipping each input source individually in my scenes. This is extremely tedious especially since I go back and forth between apps that need my virtual cam flipped or not.

Instead of flipping every source individually it would make sense to just have an option to flip the virtual camera. I don't seem to see any settings for this (mac), but I have seen youtube videos of folks on PCs that seem to have this option (image below) to flip the entire virtual camera. Thier settings are under tools > virtual cam or something like this.

[image]

I'm not sure if they have some kind of plugin that I don't or what's up. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the virtual camera, then in the top ribbon go to Edit>Transform>Flip Horizontal. There doesn't seem to be a properties or right click option from the dashboard, if you will.